# Unable to sign out Devise user when concurrent requests are not finished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, devise, angularjs, logout

The classical application structure for Devise authentication gem is server-side only Rails application. In this case when one signs out nothing prevents the session destruction.

But I am using Rails+Devise+Angular.js and try to do sign out in a right manner - it means - `/users/sign_out` URL has to be called by Angular application and not by click on `<a href="/users/sign_out">` link.

My application loads data in chunks. If some data request has not finished while /users/sign_out URL is called, Devise re-logins the user.

I made my custom logout method to see what happens:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def data_request
  .............
end

def logout
  sign_out(current_user)
  if current_user
    puts 'Has not signed out!'
  else
    puts 'Has signed out!'
  end
  redirect_to '/users/sign_out'
end
```

After `sign_out` method call the `current_user` is really `nil`, but then the very next request to data_request passes through `before_filter` as if I haven't logged out.

I would appreciate if you help me to understand what happens and how to implement a reliable logout.

**Update**

I have encountered a strange behaviour:

If I stop the Webrick server, start it again and reload page, application allows me to call API methods as if the session wasn't destroyed. As I know, the Devise's authentication cookie does not contain encrypted/encoded login and password but represents a temporary session id which should be valid only if a particular session is alive and after session destruction should become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

What method you are passing when url has been called by Angular application? device expect delete method by default for logout url.Try changing your device config file (config/initializers/devise.rb) and modify sign_out_via attribute. By default it is :delete, you just need to change to :get.

```
config/initializers/devise.rb
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Comment: the sign out method is currently set to GET, but it doesn't make any difference. I have tried DELETE, GET, POST - the behaviour is always the same.